# C# Windows Form - Serial Port problem / BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, serial-port, backgroundworker

I developed a Windows Form application, using C#, that receives data through the serial port sent by a microcontroller. I'm receiving the data using the serialPort_DataReceived event in which I use ReadLine() to read the serial port. Then I use the Invoke method to call a function that will print the received string into a textBox. The problem is that the app can't keep up with the rate at which it receives the strings, for example, the string that I send from the microcontroller has the time at which it was sent and even though it has already passed 2 or 3 seconds the app is still printing the strings that were sent at the 0.2 second. And when I send a string to the microcontroller to stop sending data, the app onlys stops ptinting the data after a while, this is, it keeps printing the values stored in the receiving buffer.

I believe that is happens given the large amount of data that the app receives and the rate (I'm using a baud rate of 115200), one string for every millisecond. This is, I think that the app is always being interrupted by the DataReceived event and it doesn't has time to print the data and starts falling behind.

One way I though of overcome this problem was with multi-threading but I can't figure it out how. I already tried a few examples using the BackgroundWorker but I didn't manage to make it work at all. I'm still a noob in terms of programming Windows Form apps and even C#.

Can anyone confirm the cause of the problem? And how do I make a thread to print the received data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize [`SerialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.receivedbytesthreshold?view=netframework-4.7.2) property and [`SerialPort.ReadExisting()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting) method (or a `StringBuilder` instance) to update UI with a batch of strings at once rather than a single string.

For more information check:

- [Serial port DataReceived firing too much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273918/serial-port-datareceived-firing-too-much) discussions on StackOverflow
- [Top 5 SerialPort Tips](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-kim-hamilton/) article by Kim Hamilton
- [Serial Port ReadLine vs ReadExisting or how to read the data from serial port properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636758/serial-port-readline-vs-readexisting-or-how-to-read-the-data-from-serial-port-pr) discussion on StackOverflow
- [Quickest way to Update Multiline Textbox with Large Amount of Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387388/quickest-way-to-update-multiline-textbox-with-large-amount-of-text) discussion on StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for answering, changing from ReadLine() to ReadExisting() solved the problem. But now I have another problem that is how do I split the string, to plot in a chart, given that now instead of having one string I have multiple strings stored in just one. The string has following format: "value time \n" where value goes from 0 to 1024 and time is in seconds and has 4 decimal places. Before I just had one string at each time so I used .Split(' ') but now given that the string changed I can't make it work, I already tried to do in a loop but with no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: String parsing problem seems unrelated to the initial question. If the answer solved your initial problem please consider accepting it and asking a new question to keep discussions of unrelated questions separate.